# When a column has a certain string, i want to replace it with a string from my left join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was wondering if anyone could help. I want my main table to keep the meter records in my main table and when i get 'Others' i want these to be replaced by the left join tables.

The issue is when im doing my case when, my result is coming back as null?
The thing is with the data im left joining too it has a lot of other data that i have to filter and a join on with which might make this question a bit more complicated. First of all i just want to make sure my case when is working correctly before i do anymore testing.

Thanks!

```
WITH CTE_MAIN AS (

SELECT DISTINCT

    EX.Meter,
    CASE WHEN (EX.Metermodel) = 'Other'
        THEN OJ.Metermodel
        ELSE EX.Metermodel
        END AS MeterModelRemoved

FROM `MAINTABLE` AS EX 
LEFT JOIN `LEFTTABLE` AS OJ ON EX.METER=OJ.METER)

SELECT * #Test 
FROM CTE_MAIN
WHERE Meter = 'G4A50027940101'
```

**Main Table**

| METER | Metermodel |
| --- | --- |
| G4A50027940101 | Other |
| 000807612 | Other |
| L0117797762M | Other |
| 009X091 | U6 |
| 5046314S | G4 |

**Left join table**

| METER | Metermodel |
| --- | --- |
| G4A50027940101 | U6 |
| 000807612 | G4 |
| L0117797762M | G4 |
| 009X091 | U6 |
| 5046314S | LPG |

**Result**: MeterModelRemoved = *null*

Comment: I see no issues with your case expression.  any record in main containing 'Other' in Metermodel will have the metermodelremoved value set to the value from the left join, if it's not 'Other', it will have it's value set from the main table.  I'd have to test the edge case of metermodel is null in your data .  I'm not sure how the case expression would handle that.  I think it goes to the else since it's not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few more options:

In case if both tables have exact same structure (as it is in your question) - consider below approach

```
select if(t1.Metermodel = 'Other', t2, t1).*
from MainTable t1
left join LeftTable t2
using(METER)
```

in case if structure of second table is different and potentially has more columns that you don't need in output - use classic approach

```
select METER, if(t1.Metermodel = 'Other', t2.Metermodel, t1.Metermodel) as Metermodel
from MainTable t1
left join LeftTable t2
using(METER)
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - both have same output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only time you will have null value is if there is no matching record in the second table. If you want to handle this, you can use the value from the main table as a fallback, which can be done using COALESCE.

```
CASE WHEN (EX.Metermodel) = 'Other'
    THEN COALESCE(OJ.Metermodel, EX.Metermodel)
    ELSE EX.Metermodel
    END AS MeterModelRemoved
```